# HTML Local Storage for Time Series Data

Tags: html, time-series, local, indexeddb

I developed a browser app that interactively charts subsets of a larger time series. This data is served as CSV based on query params e.g date range.  Often the server is slow in delivering data to the user depending on their location, the server's load or other [random unexplained] events. Unfortunately, the server infrastructure is out of my control.

For my (presently favoured) solution, I plan to implement a local storage feature that can be filled on request, trading-off many small annoying delays for one manageable initial delay, this way preserving the server API and reusing previously requested data.

So, WebSQL seems like a good fit, but I read it may disappear.  IndexedDB is recommended, but I don't see it being suitable for time series data (subset queries, frequency averaging).  So:

1. Are any of my assumptions/conclusions false?
2. Is there a local storage technology I'm missing (chrome's local file access didn't work and would be impractical anyway)?
3. Am I doomed to failure when really I ought to use a local server or some offline app (desktop, chrome extension)?

Comment: I should mention that these datasets are expected to be between 5-50MB and mostly ~ 10MB.

Comment: Indexeddb work well, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built the app with WebSQL which works very well.  My assumptions were fine and I was not doomed to failure.  I will take future risk of removal (which I see as low) for two reasons:

1. It buys me time to experiment with alternatives
2. I expect there to be plugins to fill the gap should it be removed, a la phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support all browsers you have to use both webSQL and indexedDB.  Safari and Chrome on iOS (which is really Safari) does not support indexedDB.  webSQL is dead so you don't want to use it if you don't. indexedDB works great for objects.  unlike local storage which only works with strings.

i've built an app that works in all browsers but it not a simple thing to do.  But it can be done!